# Only one file is writing in to the zip

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to write multiple xssf files to the zip and download it. Am using the following code but every time only one xssf file is there in the zip folder.
Am using JSF to download the zip.

public void downloadData() throws Exception {

```
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    setSourceList(new ArrayList<String>());
    setTargetList(new ArrayList<String>());

    List<String> tempList = dualList.getTarget();

    System.out.println(tempList.size());

    if (tempList != null && tempList.size() > 0) {

        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
        ec.responseReset();

        ec.setResponseContentType("application/zip");
        ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Export.zip\"");
        ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(outByteStream);
        OutputStream outStream = ec.getResponseOutputStream();

        for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {

            outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            zip = new ZipOutputStream(outByteStream);
            // outStream = ec.getResponseOutputStream();

            int id = ownerNameIdMap.get(tempList.get(i));
            String oName = tempList.get(i);
            String fileName = oName + ".xlsx";

            if (petList != null && petList.size() > 0) {
                petList.clear();
            }

            workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();

            OwnerModel ownerModel = ownerMap.get(id);
            ownerFirstName = ownerModel.getFirstName();
            ownerLastName = ownerModel.getLastName();
            workSheet = workBook.createSheet(ownerLastName + ", " + ownerFirstName);
            petList = iOwnerRepository.getActivePetsOfOwner(ownerModel.getId());
            petCount = petList.size();
            createMasterSheet();
            renderSheet(ownerModel);

            workBook.write(outByteStream);
            addEntry(zip, fileName, outByteStream);
            workBook.write(zip);

            outStream.write(outByteStream.toByteArray());
            outStream.flush();

        }
        outStream.close();

        // zip.closeEntry();
        zip.close();
        fc.responseComplete();

    }

}
 public void addEntry(ZipOutputStream zip, String filename, ByteArrayOutputStream os) {

     System.out.println(filename);
        byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();

    //    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
      //  Date d = new Date();
       // entry.setTime(d.getTime());
        try {
            ((ZipOutputStream) zip).putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filename));
            ((ZipOutputStream) zip).write(bytes);
            ((ZipOutputStream) zip).closeEntry();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Can't read the file !", e);
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            log.error("Bad format !", cce);
        }
 }
```

Comment: So what did you debug? And how is JSF that use use in the download, related to the content of the file that **you** created? Did you try creating it as a file server-side and check the contents then? is tempList.size() always 1? Please do some more investigation.

Comment: Size of templist is not always 1. It has to generate that many workbooks and write into the Zip. It is adding different files to the zip outputstream but every time files getting replaced with the new one. So only the last file exist in the Zip.

Comment: Then it is not jsf related. And try in a unit test of a plain pojo